# ログイン機能の　header locationについて

Tags: php, mysql

プログラミング初心者で、現在phpを利用してログイン画面を作成しました。
しっかりとした本などは所持していないため、基本的に検索ベースで作業しています。

初めてで、尚且つ不慣れた状態でしたので
①とにかく具体例を参照
②分からない箇所は調べる（それでも理解しきれない箇所も有）
③基本のフォーマットが分からないため、コピペ
④自分の作成したいwebページの形に変形
という形で行いました。

この作業過程で分からないところがあったので質問させてください。
■質問

> ?php
>   session_start();
>
> // ログイン状態チェック
>   if (!isset($_SESSION["ID"])) {
>      header("Location: login.php");
>      exit;
>   }
>   ?

このようにログイン状態を表す際や、ログインの時にheaderのlocationとありますがこれは何をしめしているのでしょうか？

ログインの際はpassword_verifyのif節の中に格納したので、パスワードが認証されればlocation以下のファイルに飛ぶ、と認識していました。
しかしログイン状態の時は特にどこかのページに飛ぶ機能が備わっているわけではないので、理解できませんでした。

ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["ID"])){
```

[$_SESSION["ID"]が存在しない時。](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.isset.php)

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

ブラウザーに対して、login.phpへリダイレクトする様に、[生の HTTP ヘッダを送信する。](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.header.php)

```
exit;
```

処理を終了する（ここで止める）

```
}
```

ログイン状態の時はここから先に処理を記述します。

```
echo 'hello!!';
```

とか

Comment: 当方の表現した「ページへ飛ぶ」というのはリダイレクトというのですね、ありがとうございます。phpファイルに限らず、httpを直接入れられることも分かりました。丁寧な解説助かります。